# What does "bella ciao" mean literally?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, grammar, vocabulary, grammatical-analysis

Is "bella" considered as an adjective and "ciao"  as a noun?
OR  "bella" is the addressee and "ciao" is an interjection meaning "goodbye".

Stated differently, is it translated as "beautiful goodbye/ beautiful farewell" OR "O beautiful, goodbye/ goodbye, beautiful"?

** This is the famous partisan song. I first heard it in La Casa de Papel.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Can you explain more precisely in which context you found the expression?

Comment: @DenisNardin:  Immagino si tratti della famosa canzone dei partigiani.

Comment: @Charo Sospetto anch'io, ma se l'OP confermasse sarebbe meglio :)

Comment: Sì, questa è la famosa canzone partigiana.

Comment: Yes, this is the famous partisan song. I first heard it in La Casa de Papel.

Comment: Should probably be written *bella, ciao!* since that's the meaning in the song.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The second one**, definitely. *Bye, beautiful*.

I would translate *A beautiful goodbye* as *Un bel saluto* or *Un bell'addio*  (masculine --- I'm not sure why, but in practice these kinds of salutations and interjections all get the masculine), and *What a beautiful goodbye* to *Che bell'addio*. All of these sound a bit awkward to my ear.

You can also say *un bel ciao* (again masculine --- as can be seen also in the recently popular meme [*ciaone*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ciaone_%28Neologismi%29/)), but I would take it to mean "a nice, friendly salutation with the word *ciao*". Note that *ciao* in Italian does not have the meaning of "farewell / final parting salutation" that goodbye has in English. If you wish to stress the fact that you won't see someone ever again, you use the more dramatic *addio*. So in the text of this song it's just a casual salutation.

As @DenisNardin points out in a comment (thanks!), the word *ciao* in Italian is a generic salutation used with the informal register (*dare del tu*), and is used indifferently both when meeting (like *hello*) and when parting (like *bye*). Given the context of the song I would choose to translate it to *goodbye*, but both meanings are possible.

Comment: You already alluded to it, but it might be worth specifying that *ciao* in Italian means both *bye* and *hello*, so *un bel ciao* could also mean *a nice greeting*.

Comment: “I'm not sure why, but in practice these kinds of salutations and interjections all get the masculine”: Just because. :) I'd say there is no precise “why”... Why is _tavolo_ masculine and _sedia_ feminine? (Yes, sometimes because Latin etc., but there is no real “because”.) And by the way, at the very least _buonanotte_ and _buonasera_, as nouns, are feminine.

Comment: *buonanotte and buonasera, as nouns, are feminine.* Are they? Would you say "Mi salutò con un buonasera" or "Mi salutò con una buonasera"? The first one sounds correct to me, and Google seems to return more results for the first expression.

Comment: My ear (which of course is no authority, but I find _un buonasera_ weird), [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/buonasera), [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/buonasera) and Zingarelli all agree on feminine for _buonasera_ and _buonanotte_...

Comment: And, would you say “Ti ho chiamato per darti il buonanotte”?

Comment: Thanks for you all 